# Opencv: reduce video acquisition aperture

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am using OpenCV and python3 to use a camera and perform a real-time depth map. 
In order to try to increase the fps, I would like to try to don't collect all the scene, but just an aperture of height= 10 pixels and width equal to all camera aperture ( as what I need is just a raw vector ). 
Is it possible to do it without process all data, maybe modifying the camera aperture? 
will it affect my depth map quality?
thanks for any answer

Comment: That primarily depends on the camera -- what kind/model is it? Additionally, very few VideoIO backends in OpenCV support configuring this. e.g. all the industrial GigEVision cameras I've worked with support this, but the PVAPI backend in OpenCV doesn't let you set it. (I guess patching it in would be quite trivial in this case)

Comment: the camera is a stereo camera module with USB connection. real simple camera without analogic settings.
something like ELS dual lens. 
what i had think to do was to use ROI to focus on the area of interest and then to apply a mask to the other part of the scene.
But as my purpose is to reduce the amount of data to speed up the process, will this work? Will i reduce the fps going in this way